# AngularJS using How to render video (.wmv,.mpg,.mpeg,.mkv,.avi,.m4v) formats?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video, html5-video

I am using HTML5 video tag but video tag only suports [check Browser compatibility point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

I want to supports (.wmv,.mpg,.mpeg,.mkv,.avi,.m4v) formats,
Provide any thaird party tool or any idea using javacript.

Perpuse :

- I have video url and that url I need to play on the website.

Comment: You can convert the `.wmv,.mpg,.mpeg,.mkv,.avi,.m4v` formats to `ogg, webm, mp4` by any online tool. So these `ogg, webm, mp4` three formats can support in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Windows and MAC Safari browsers